# Changing bootstrap from one row to multiple four separate rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently having an issue with bootstrap. I was wondering if there is a trick with css or in the html, to switch it when the site is on mobile.

currently the row is set up which is good for desktop
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2,

and i need to switch it to 
6,6
6,6
6,6
6,6 
when the site when the screen width is 750 or less 
can someone point me in the right direction.

thank you

Comment: take a look at this. You will get all of your question answered here. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Please share code using jsfiddle or codepen for us to help better. From the top of my head i think you can use @media screen (max-width:750px) query for this along with using bootstrap col-xs, col-sm, col-md and col-lg respectively with nested rows to set it up that way.

Comment: Thank you for the help found what I needed on that site. It is my first time with bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The `.col-xs-` class is used for extra small devices phones (<768px) and the `.col-md-` class is used for medium devices desktops (≥992px). You can use the code below for resizing your content according to the different resolutions.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">...</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">...</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">...</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">...</div>
</div>
```

Adding `.clearfix` and `.visible-xs-block` classes is optional, they clear the xs columns if their content doesn't match in height.